# Speech To Text using C#

Tags: c#, .net, speech-to-text

I am trying to design a text editor using C# language and implement voice recognition for the normal file features , is this possible to implement.
I am very sorry if I am repeating the question which has been asked previously.
I just want to know if there are ways in converting the Speech to Text using C#.
Your help is really valuable .
Awaiting for response.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. as of now its not that accurate. please read [Whatever Happened to Voice Recognition?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/06/whatever-happened-to-voice-recognition.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete example using C# and System.Speech for converting from speech to text

The code can be divided into 2 main parts:

configuring the SpeechRecognitionEngine object (and its required elements)
handling the SpeechRecognized and SpeechHypothesized events.

**Step 1: Configuring the SpeechRecognitionEngine**

```
_speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
_speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
_dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
_speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(_dictationGrammar);
_speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

At this point your object is ready to start transcribing audio from the microphone. You need to handle some events though, in order to actually get access to the results.

**Step 2: Handling the SpeechRecognitionEngine Events**

> _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized -= new EventHandler(SpeechRecognized);
>   _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechHypothesized -= new EventHandler(SpeechHypothesizing);
>
> _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler(SpeechRecognized);
>   _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler(SpeechHypothesizing);
>
> private void SpeechHypothesizing(object sender,
>   SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs e) { 
>   ///real-time results from the engine
>   string realTimeResults = e.Result.Text; }
>
> private void SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs
>   e) { 
>   ///final answer from the engine string finalAnswer =
>   e.Result.Text; }

That’s it. If you want to use a pre-recorded .wav file instead of a microphone, you would use

> _speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToWaveFile(pathToTargetWavFile);

instead of

> _speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

There are a bunch of different options in these classes and they are worth exploring in more detail.

http://ellismis.com/2012/03/17/converting-or-transcribing-audio-to-text-using-c-and-net-system-speech/

Answer (score 2):

You can use try SharpSphinx A C# version of Sphinx-4 
http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/sphinx4-sightings/thread/5953c635/?limit=50

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly the [Microsoft Speech SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Speech_API) supports speech to text.

Answer (score 1):

Then there's the [LumenVox Speech Engine](http://www.lumenvox.com/products/speech_engine/).

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [iSpeech API](http://www.ispeech.org/api), which could be used for speech recognition as a web service.